# Implementing side menu in apple maps like map via pulley

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I’m building an app that is similar to apple maps but I want to implement a side menu. Currently I’m using pulley to imitate my app like apple map but while using pulley I’m not being able to implement side menu. 
I’m using the same technique in another app and side menu works absolutely fine but in pulley implemented app, side menu just doesn’t show up neither the app gives any error.

I think the issue is in constraints, can you please tell me how to play with constraints to move map and drawer view controller to a side so that side menu shows up.